# Inserting and saving xml using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

If i have an XML file `settings.xml` like below

```
<Root>
    <First>
    </First>
</Root>
```

I Load the XML first using `XDocument settings = XDocument.Load("settings.xml")`

How should I insert a XML node inside the node `First` and save it using LINQ-to-XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find the `First` element. Then you can add other elements and attributes to it.
There are more than one way to find an element in the xml: `Elements`, `Descendants`, `XPathSelectElement`, etc.

```
var firstElement = settings.Descendants("First").Single();
firstElement.Add(new XElement("NewElement"));

settings.Save(fileName);
// or
var newXml = settings.ToString();
```

Output:

```
<Root>
  <First>
    <NewElement />
  </First>
</Root>
```

Or element with attribute:

```
firstElement.Add(
   new XElement("NewElement", new XAttribute("NewAttribute", "TestValue")));
```

Output:

```
<Root>
  <First>
    <NewElement NewAttribute="TestValue" />
  </First>
</Root>
```

**[Edit]** The answer to the bonus question. What to do if the first element does not exist and I want to create it:

```
var root = settings.Element("Root");
var firstElement = root.Element("First");
if (firstElement == null)
{
    firstElement = new XElement("First");
    root.Add(firstElement);
}
firstElement.Add(new XElement("NewElement"));
```

Comment: @Bhaskar K - I just saw the answer mark, and then it's gone? :(

Comment: Sometimes if node "First" might not be there, how can I check and create that node, then create child node under it.

Comment: oops sorry, I will accept it now :), but it would be great if you can answer me the above ques too. :)